# Springers svmult template - bibliography with bibtex?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm using [Springers (free) `svmult` template](http://www.springer.com/authors?SGWID=0-111-2-791599-0&changeHeader) to compose a book as editor with several individual contribution by different authors. Every author should be able to have his own bibliography at the end of his contributions.

Technically, this is a master file (`editor.tex`) with many included files (`author1.tex`, `author2.tex` ...)

In the author.tex template, there is the following advice:

```
%
%
% BibTeX users please use
% \bibliographystyle{}
% \bibliography{}
%
% Non-BibTeX users please follow the syntax
% the syntax of "referenc.tex" for your own citations
\input{referenc}
```

Now I tried several ways to use

```
\bibliographystyle{}
\bibliography{}
```

(of course with style and file specified):

1. only in the master file -> doesn't work
2. in each author file -> latex complains about more than one style/bibliography file found
3. the style in the masterfile, the bibliography in each author file - > prints the *complete* bibliography at the end of each contribution, not only the bibliography for that contribution.

Now I'm a bit stuck - how can I realize one separate bibliography for each contribution in the book?

Comment: You can use `biblatex`. The class allows these settings.