# Springers svmult template - chapter-wise bibliography with bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, sv-classes

I have exactly the same problem as that described in the following question, which was (weirdly) closed:

[Springers svmult template - bibliography with bibtex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65634/77816)

Can this question please be re-opened?

I'm sure it's an issue that is encountered by many multi-author volume editors!

Kind regards,
Dave

Comment: Hi and welcome, the question was most likely closed because the mechanism for Springer doesn't differ from the standard classes. Most likely it is a duplicateas well, and should have been closed as such. On the other hand, doing chapterwise bibliographies with BibTeX is a bit of a pain, whereas it is a piece of cake using `biblatex` and `biber`.